# macOS: Adding a divider between NSMenu NSMenuItem's?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

How do you add dividers to a status bar menu in code? E.g.

```
let menu = NSMenu()
let editMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
editMenuItem.title = "Preferences..."
menu.addItem(editMenuItem)

let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
quitMenuItem.title = "Quit"
menu.addItem(quitMenuItem)

self.statusBarItem.menu = menu
```

In this example, I'd like to add a divider between the first and second items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean a *separator* there is a [class method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514838-separator)

```
let menu = NSMenu()
let editMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
editMenuItem.title = "Preferences…"
menu.addItem(editMenuItem)

menu.addItem(.separator())

let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
quitMenuItem.title = "Quit"
menu.addItem(quitMenuItem)

self.statusBarItem.menu = menu
```

Comment: The lines are also called dividers. There is no need to be so prescriptive with language.